# Instead of Chapter it shows as a "Kapitel"

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I was wondering why my chapter name shows as "Kapitel" instead of "Chapter"

Here is the error

[image]

Here is my Latex code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textcomp} %for apostrophe
\usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}% Http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float,xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\include{c0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` is the cause, I think.

Comment: I did that but it is still the same.

Comment: Well, in which language do you write your document? With `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` you get german names for chapter etc. If you want to write in english use `\usepackage[english]{babel}`. BTW `hyperref ` should be called last, do not call packages twice!

Comment: A lot of people start by copying package lists from other people’s documents. I’d recommend against that. If removing a package doesn’t cause you an error, you probably should.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as resolved in the comments